# SQL Query takes hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to move a C# Forms Programm from an old server to a new one. And it seems to work but now although the server has better hardware the SQL queries running like forever. I'm not so much into SQL but this following query seems to be the slowest when I'm debugging the code. Maybe someone has a solution or an idea why it's so lame....

This is the basic SQL:

```
DECLARE @id nvarchar(255); 
DECLARE @tag nvarchar(255); 
DECLARE curAuftr CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY 
FOR 
SELECT AUSF_TAG, SAP_ID FROM  TabellenName 
OPEN curAuftr 
FETCH NEXT FROM curAuftr INTO @tag, @id 
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) 
BEGIN 
UPDATE  TabellenName 
SET SummePersonal = 
(select Sum(Stunden) from LStunden 
WHERE 
convert(varchar(10), Datum, 104) LIKE @tag 
AND KFZInnenauftrag_Nummer LIKE @id 
AND NOT 
( Mitarbeiter_Kostenstelle LIKE (PC + '%') 
AND Mitarbeiter_Kostenstelle LIKE '%055' 
AND PC LIKE 'U%' ) 
)
WHERE 
AUSF_TAG = @tag
AND SAP_ID = @id 
FETCH NEXT FROM curAuftr INTO @tag, @id 
END 
CLOSE curAuftr 
DEALLOCATE curAuftr
```

Comment: Because cursors are slow, you could do that entire update with 1 single update statement.

Comment: Why cursor? What is the actual requirement to your update?

Comment: Using a bunch of LIKE operations in a cursor with multiple subquery is *extremely* expensive in SQL.

Comment: This isn't really a C# issue. The issue is your query. Please edit your question and extract your query from those string concatenations, and then give table and schema definitions and explain the intent of the query.

Comment: Well I#m not even really sure what a cursor really is....

Comment: Then the first step to improving your code is actually *understanding* your code!

Comment: That's the problem it's not mine. I have no idea why the solution needs a cursor.

Comment: We're not a code writing service. Your query needs to be refactored, and it's not necessarily a trivial one. You're going to need to brush up on how TSQL queries work and figure out how to refactor this query to not use a cursor. Do you guys not have a DBA that does this kind of work?

Comment: BY FAR the biggest issue here is that you are wide open to sql injection. Then add to it the horrific cursor based approach and you have a super slow and incredibly dangerous process here. You need to use parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: A cursor is a SQL construct that processes one row at a time. In a table that is of any size this will take many, many times longer then processing the entire table (as a set) at one time. Processing an entire set does not mean every row just every row that meets an arbitrary condition. Set processing is typically very fast whereas row by row processing is slower by some very large factor,

Comment: There also appears to be some major architecture issues here. You seem to have tables broken down by dates. This kind of information should be in a column with all of the data in a single place. It avoids the nightmare types of sql you have to deal with now.

Comment: Cursors are inherently slow and should only be used for small amounts of records, and only in edge cases where there's absolutely no way around it.  This looks like something that was written by someone that clearly didn't know of a better way to do it, and should be refactored the way @BerndOtt pointed out in the answer below (note - I haven't tested that code yet, but at a quick glance, that appears to be the correct way to address it).  Being that this is a mass update, dupe your tables over and play around with it to make sure the results match the original query.

Comment: I don't this cursors are slow. Depends on how you are opening them. firehose (forward & readonly) are really fast. The time consuming parts are the required loops by creating hundreds of subquerys.

Comment: True, I should have clarified that....it's more so the looping constructs and subqueries, which appear to be being abused in this case.  Using `like` conditions within the subquery probably isn't helping matters very much either, though that may not be avoidable.

Comment: @BerndOtt I disagree with your assessment of cursors and performance. Yes your firehouse cursor is a really fast way to use a slow mechanism but a set based approach will blow away a cursor any day.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will try to implement @Bernt Ott solution. Maybe i will study cursors although I don't see any scenario where I need them. Till know I only have used joins and subquerys... SQL Injections seems not to be a (big) problem here because it's on an intranet.

Comment: The only time SQL injection ISN'T a problem is if you can guarantee the input will be clean (which is all but impossible to do).  You should really use best practices at all times, as to not get into sloppy habits, even if you do trust your users not to enter in data that might potentially destroy your database.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is to have one query as source for the update where statement. Its the same table, i don't know why you are doing that.
This forces you the that cursor. Updates can update multiple rows.
Reduce the problem to the update command only.

The subquery which creates the sum is executed for every row. This is time killing part. Create a subquery which creates the sums and join the result also to the update.

Also very slow is the Date to String conversion the compare it with the like command.

Untested code sample, because you didn't provide any sample tables:

```
UPDATE TabellenName
SET SummePersonal = StundenSumme
from TabellenName join 
(
select Sum(Stunden) as Stunden, convert(varchar(10), Datum, 104) as TAG, KFZInnenauftrag_Nummer as ID  from LStunden 
WHERE NOT ( Mitarbeiter_Kostenstelle LIKE (PC + '%') AND Mitarbeiter_Kostenstelle LIKE '%055' AND PC LIKE 'U%' ) 
group by convert(varchar(10), Datum, 104), KFZInnenauftrag_Nummer 
) summen
on TabellenName.AUSF_TAG=summen.tag and TabellenName.SAP_ID=summen.id)
```

Try to use the management studio and display the query plan to find the bottle necks.